# Flask/Python calling def in approute

Tags: python-2.7, flask

This might be a stupid question, but I am new to coding with Python.
Using flask and calling `@app.route()`, i need to create several HTML files. 
Rather then coding everything inside of `@app.route()`, can i call different `def` inside the `app.route` before returning the `render_template`?

**Edit:**

So i am creating HTML files. Rather then opening 3-4 different documents inside the `app.route` and printing lines to them, can I create 3-4 functions in the main code to handle each document.

so rather then:

```
@app.route('/')
   Print all html files
```

have:

```
def html1(): 
    write html files 

@app.route('/') 
    html1()
    render_template
```

Comment: Please provide some more information. Are you trying to call a function from your route handling function?

Comment: What do you mean by writing html files?

Comment: Im sorry I really have not given enough information. I am using a Linux server and writing web apps suing flask for a class. I have to edit write HTML files based on information that I pull from a form. I open the HTML file and write lines to it, then close it. But i need to do that for several pages

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do that's different than just rendering jinja templates in the normal fashion.

Comment: Are you saying you want to write a bunch of html files to the file system in response to a request and then to server them?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do whatever processing you need to inside a route before finally returning the response to the client. Be aware of load times, however - people don't like waiting long for a page to load.

That being said, you should **really** take a look at the [template tutorial](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/tutorial/templates/) of the [official docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/). Your approach sounds like a **perfect** place to make use of templates as Jinja is doing what you describe, but in real-time: taking the HTML file, replacing certain places with your data, and presenting that to the user.